# Why Pandas fillna method does not work with pd.NA values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, na

According to the [reference page of Pandas.DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), all NA/NaN values are filled using the specified method.

However, in presence of pd.NA values it does not work.

As you can see in the following code block in fact, if I want to replace missing booleans (marked with the pd.NA values) with the column's mode it does not work:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [True, pd.NA, False, True], "b": [0, np.nan, 2, 3]})

# convert types (a becomes boolean, b becomes Int64)
df = df.convert_dtypes()

# get boolean columns
bool_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=bool).columns.tolist()

# get most frequent values
most_frequent_values = df[bool_cols].mode()

# replace missing content with column's mode
df[bool_cols] = df[bool_cols].fillna(most_frequent_values)

# print
print(df)
```

This is the current output:

| id | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | True | 0 |
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 | False | 2 |
| 3 | True | 3 |

while this is the expected output:

| id | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | True | 0 |
| 1 | True |  |
| 2 | False | 2 |
| 3 | True | 3 |

What am I missing? Should I convert all pd.NA in NaNs?

Side note: My Pandas version is 1.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that [`mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html) doesn't return a single value but a 2D output.

You need to change:

```
most_frequent_values = df[bool_cols].mode().loc[0] # take the first mode

# then fillna
df[bool_cols] = df[bool_cols].fillna(most_frequent_values)
```

Then the output is correct:

```
       a     b
0   True     0
1   True  <NA>
2  False     2
3   True     3
```